# Difference between request.user vs. get_user(request) in Django?

Tags: python, django

I noticed there are two ways to get a user object from request (assuming user is already logged in and the session is valid):

- `user = request.user`
- `user = get_user(request)` where `get_user()` is imported from `django.contrib.auth`.

What's the difference? `get_user()` seems to do a lot of validation for request session.

Which is better?

Comment: Looking at the implementation of `get_user()`, it would seem it's just a `request.user` call with some extra validation, as you said. Unless you plan on doing this verification yourself anyways, using `get_user` could simply save you some code.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

‍‍‍‍`request.user` is actually populated with `get_user(request)`.

It happens in `AuthenticationMiddleware`:

```py
request.user = SimpleLazyObject(lambda: get_user(request))
```

So when you get `request.user`, you are actually getting `get_user(request)` result.

Comment: add official source FYI: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.user

Comment: It would be redundant to use `get_user(request)` in my case. Thank you.